# Can FB Graph API Explorer be used to download group data from Closed groups?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

i know the FB Graph API works for open groups, to download that group's data. But it doesn't seem to work for Closed groups *that i am a member of*.

When i get an Access Token (after clicking user_groups in the 'Select Permissions' dialog box), and then run a GET on https://www.facebook.com/groups/426721967404475/feed, these are the results i get:

```
"id": "788215564563612",
"created_time": "2014-09-03T23:14:16+0000",
"is_scraped": false,
"type": "website",
"updated_time": "2014-09-03T23:14:16+0000",
"url": "https://www.facebook.com/groups/426721967404475/feed"
```

The results should be showing as the group's contents, like they do for Open groups.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks!